# Why this pice of code is not working?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

This block of code is **not working**

```
 <td><a href = "delete.php?id = <?php echo $row['id'];?>" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
```

But when I **edit** the code like:

```
 <td><a href = "delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
```

**Then it works**. Is there any **explanations**?

Comment: share full line with html tag

Comment: All you need to do for proper formatting is indent with four spaces or use the `{}` button to do it for you on highlighted text.

Comment: not works <td><a href = "delete.php?id = <?php echo $row['id'];?>" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>

Works <td><a href = "delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>

Comment: The error is by the whitespaces into the URL, `id = `

Comment: With the whitespaces, the `$_GET` will look like `["id_"]=> string(3) " 12"`, without: `["id"]=> string(2) "12"`.

Comment: Assuming `$row['id]` is `123`, the first piece of code generates the URL `.../delete.php?id = 123`, the second one generates `.../delete.php?id=123`. The whitespace characters are not ignored in URLs and this makes `"id "` (`id` followed by a space) different than `"id"`.

Answer (score 0):

Cause might be the space after id and = sign `"delete.php?id = <?php echo $row['id'];?>"`

will be better if you share your full code

Comment: <tbody>
       <tr>
        <?php while($row = $rows->fetch_assoc()) {?>       
         <th><?php echo $row['id'];?></th>
         <td class = "col-md-10"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
         <td><a href = "" class = "btn btn-success">Edit</a></td>
         <td><a href = "delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>        
       </tr>
        <?php }?>
       
      </tbody>

Comment: You said that this line <td><a href = "delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>

is working and above one not this must be the issue of blank space after id and =

Comment: Why the blank spaces matter here?

Comment: blank space is counted as parameter too that is why it is facing issues you can use 
"delete.php?id=' <?php echo $row['id'];?>'" like this and while getting the value use trim() hope it will work fine

Comment: Just and example. Simply because `delete.php?id=3` !==  `delete.php?id= 3`, when translated as http request it will be `delete.php?id=%203`